# Where is located http://www.springframework.org/schema/p that appear with 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I am developing a netbeans web server with spring MVC in dispatcher-servlet.xml file the header that was generated automatically looks like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
```

and in some part of the xml I have this

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

the suffix p is used but when I access to the url http://www.springframework.org/schema/p it give me a 404

sorry but I'm new in java and I don't know too much

how can I fix this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you thinking that you need to "access the URL" at all? This isn't so much a Spring/Java question as it is an XML Schema question. (As a side note, manual XML-style configuration for Spring applications is mostly outdated. I suggest looking at the official Spring Getting Started Guides and using Spring Boot, which, for example, would register that bean for you with no configuration necessary.)

Comment: I need access to that url to avoid errors when I run the application
the error say that need p

Comment: I have the same problem. Yesterday it worked, now P is not accessible anymore.

Comment: All nice and peachy, but I am "revisiting" an old application and don't want to touch what is supposed to be working. It still needs that "P" schema to work. If it is just a half Kilobyte file why is it gone?

Answer (score 0):

The p schema seems to be gone. You can go back to declare the properties as it was before the p schema.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```